# How do I process the trigger file in Azure Data Factory

Tags: dynamic, triggers, azure-data-factory

I want to process a file that is placed on our Blob storage using a trigger.
The trigger looks like this:
[trigger definition:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgfhN.png)

Daily a new file is created with a data-timestamp in the name.

Q: I want to read the content of this JSON (which has a different name daily), but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To get the contents of the file which is triggering the pipeline, you need to use look up activity with parameters. First create a pipeline parameter as shown below:

[image]

- Now in look up, I have created a dataset. For this dataset, I have created a parameter to use as filename. I pass this value from pipeline using the above created parameter value.

[image]

- Now when you create the storage event trigger for this pipeline, after filling the trigger definition and clicking continue, parameters tab will be displayed. Here give the value to `fileName` pipeline parameter as `@triggerBody().fileName`.

[image]

- When a file is uploaded/created, then the filename will be captured and stored in `fileName` parameter which will be used in look up to get the content of that file.

[image]